# Switch database file in runtime

Tags: neo4j

(This question is not about having multiple databases)

Hi,

I have a use case to serve daily snapshot of our dataset through Neo4j. I am considering to build graph data daily in offline via import tool.

The reason of considering import tool is, using API or Cypher to do this will bring many problems such as long transaction, less scalable, less performant, unnecessary burden to running Neo4j instance. Also, using subgraph pattern (to load other subgraph, flip, and delete) is not desirable as it's very easy to make mistake as it's relying on good intention not good architecture.

With this "build offline and push" pattern, I am trying to use import tool to build graph data and switch graph file hopefully while Neo4j is running to remove downtime (Don't want to have multiple instance to achieve this as our deployment process is quite restrictive).

I wonder if this case is being supported.

Thanks!

Comment: To put little more on the context, I don't think it's too much to expect this as other service support this. For example, Elasticsearch supports alias index where we can do build, push, and swap all on running instance. It's seems Neo4j doesn't support build and push case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless things with Neo4J are different, pulling the datastore files out from a running instance of any database is a very bad idea.

Turn it off first, or you will interrupt the running process. Other than that, Neo4J does indeed support swapping out the graph.db directory; just be sure to bring down your instance before you start messing with its active filesystem.

Comment: That's what I thought. Additional work would be required to make it zero down time and I wondered if Neo4j already have solution for this. But thanks for clear things up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, if you've found that an answer works for you, it is helpful if you mark it as "Accepted" for the benefit of other people who may see it. Either way, I'm glad I was able to help.